# reledpar/reledmac verse and prose

Tags: reledpar

I would like to set a latin poem (left page) with a correspondinge german translation (right page).

Setting paralell prose texts is fine, but I am not able to get verse-prose to work.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage[]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}

\begin{document}

\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \begin{astanza}
                test&
test&
test&
test\&
            \end{astanza}
         \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    %
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
              German translation
            \pend
         \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have omitted to set the stanza indents.  Adding `\setstanzaindents{0,0,0,0,0}` allows the file to compile.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage[]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}

\begin{document}

\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
      \beginnumbering
      \setstanzaindents{0,0,0,0,0}
      \begin{astanza}
        test&
        test&
        test&
        test\&
      \end{astanza}
      \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    %
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
              German translation
            \pend
         \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But now i have got problems with unnumbered texts.

[...]
\pend
\pausenumbering
test unnumbered test unnumbered
\resumenumbering
\pstart
numbered
\pend
\endnumbering